# Increase Logo Size in Salesforce Experience Cloud template

Tags: digital-experience

How do I increase the logo size of the Experience Cloud Customer Service template using CSS? The default size is too small. I would like the height to be at least 100px.
https://scottdesign2-dev-ed.develop.my.site.com/s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open All Sites --> click on Builder for your site --> Settings --> Advanced --> **Edit Head Markup**

Add below markup:

```html
<style>
    .siteforceServiceBody .cBrandingLogo{
       --lwc-spacingXxLarge : 4rem;
    }
</style>
```